# Request Dialog CRASHED?

Tags: facebook, dialog, components

Recently, Facebook has updated the component "request dialog" assigning responsibility to the exclusion of requests to the developers (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests#deleting). He also made other adjustments to the format of the request id. Thus added configuration option "request 2.0 efficient" on menu of the application developer.

The problem started after this change , the component "request dialog Multi - Friend- Selector" is in serious trouble. The component is crashed while trying to load friends. Sometimes friends loads, but the component does not resize height.

See the image of the errors:

**Crashed before load friends:**

http://postimage.org/image/glk2mf3bb/

**Resize fail**

http://postimage.org/image/iobduhn41/

In chrome  browser component generates the following error:

```
s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yS/r/syXGEAW5WYH.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
```

In firefox generates following error:

```
Erro: Permission denied to access property 'DocRPC'Arquivo-fonte: https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yS/r/syXGEAW5WYH.js Linha: 36
```

**Can you reproduce the error with the code itself Documentation**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests

***Help please.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing same errors here, but I can add some info:

- It does seem to work if you use the basic example in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests, which opens up the dialog in a new browser window.
- In Chrome, I found an additional error message to the one you posted:
  "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL [...] from frame with URL [...]facebook.com/dialog/apprequests. Domains, protocols and ports must match."
- From all that I guess the error may be related to the dialog display mode (read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs). Within my app, I am getting this error exactly as you do, unless I set display to something like 'popup', in which case everything works (but a new borwser window is opened). The docs do state that "Because of the risk of clickjacking, [iframe] is only allowed for some certain dialogs, and requires you to pass a valid access_token." Well, passing access tokens did no good for me.

Little question: are you using some toolkit like GWT?

Comment: Hi Milton, you are Brazilian ?  if so, add me on gtalk: vctlzac@gmail.com

. About the error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ... I also get this error sometimes and I think that is unrelated to the problem. He received this error before having this problem.

How do I configure the component to as "pop-up"?

I do not use any toolkit.

Comment: Just use something like `FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'My Great Request', display: 'popup'}, requestCallback);`

Comment: OK, so today the error messages in the console disappeared and the list of friends shows up. Just the dialog is too small. Guess the final answer to your question is: blame it on the Facebook guys and wait until they fix it.

Comment: I also believe that we should expect correction at facebook. Meanwhile we use the component as a pop-up applying "display: 'popup' " configuration.